# How to send Verification Email after signup

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase for user signup but I could not find any method to send verification email after signup.

```
auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .addOnCompleteListener(SignupActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
            // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
            // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Authentication failed." + task.getException(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser()

                startActivity(new Intent(SignupActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send an address verification email to a user with the sendEmailVerification method. For example:

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();

user.sendEmailVerification()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Email sent.");
            }
        }
    });
```

more info here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users

Comment: That method is not available in com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2"

Comment: The email verification methods were added in [SDK version 9.6](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#sdk_version_96_september_21_2016). In general I'd recommend that you use a recent version of the Firebase SDKs. 9.0.2 is >18 months old. While it still works fine, you're missing lots of additions and improvements since then.

Comment: yes as Frank said, the latest one is 11.8.0, its better to update to that one. https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android